# Selenium + JUnit. How DRY?

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium, junit, automated-tests

My situation below:

I have couple test cases:

- user log on Site;
- user open Home Page;
- User see some information, is not so important, maybe some table or div, etc..
- User go to HelpDesk Page.
- User go to CustomPage.
- User see some custom info on the Page.
- and more and more other cases.

My task is test all this cases under different users (admin1, admin2, userWithoutAccess, etc.) via Selenium Driver and JUnit.

But, currently, I don't see any valid solution for my task :(

For example:

```
public class HelpDeskPageTest
{
    private static WebDriver driver;

    HelpDeskPage helpDeskPage;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass()
    {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        Utils.logon(driver, "admin", "1234");
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass()
    {
      driver.quit();
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        helpDeskPage = HelpDeskPage.open(driver);
    }

    @Test
    public void helpDeskPageIsOpen()
    {
        assertTrue(channelBrowserPage.getTitle().equals("Google: Internal HelpDesk"));
    }
}
```

What does this code do?
This code just tests if user admin can opens HelpDesk Page.
Also, `HelpDeskPageTest` class can contains a lof of other test methods that test admin actions on HelpDesk Page. It is all ok.

You can ask me: So, where did you see the problem? My answer below:

1. If I want test the same functionality for other user (for example: `admin2`). How can I do it? I must just create the same test class with name: `HelpDeskPageTestForAdmin2`, modify `@BeforeClass`  method (login as `admin2`) and just copy all other code from `HelpDeskPageTest`? but this is a direct violation of the principle **DRY**! 
   How can I avoid this situation?
2. Site contains a lot of different pages (`Login, Home, HelpDesk, CustomPage1, CustomPage2`...). For separate page I made separate test class (`LoginPageTest`, `HomePageTest`, `HelpDeskPageTest`). All test classes are independent on each other. In result I spend a lot of time for method `@BeforeClass` where `WebDriver` instantiate (>10sec.). It is so long! How can I avoid this time delay? How share instance within all testes?

How JUnit can help me with my problems?

Comment: Do you need to run all @test s with different login credentials?

Comment: I hope my answer would help you :)

Comment: Why you don't try QMetry Automation Framework[ https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/docs.html ] which provides different design concepts for web based test automation. For example Page using hierarchy you just need to call lunch page, The framework takes care of not only launching that page but the entire page hierarchy to reach that specific page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for sure you need some kind of parameterization. which one, depends on what exactly do you need. if you want to run *all* methods from your test class with the same set of parameters then you need `@Parameters`. then you can have your arguments, e.g. `"admin", "adminPassword"` and each method will be run with those parameters accessible.

if however you need each method with different set of parameters then:
if you know all parameters at compile time, check [zohhak](https://code.google.com/p/zohhak/). if you want parameters from file or other provider, check [junitParams](http://code.google.com/p/junitparams/)

Comment: Your suggestion of "junitParams" is not necessary. JUnit 4.11+ has parameterized support.

Comment: depends on what you need. junit's way requires a lot of boilerplate and can't have different parameters for each method. zohhak and/or junitParams let you write much cleaner code

Comment: There is no "boilerplate". That isn't true.  Also, there can be one parameterized list for each test class.  If you need more than one parameterized list then create multiple test classes.  Easy.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing here is not **unit testing**, but just using junit as a helper to run integration or system tests. This is pretty common, and not really a sign of doing anything wrong. But it does mean that the general guidelines, features and best practises that apply to *unit testing* with junit should be ignored.

So forget about one assertion per test, and most of the annotations like @Before. Just write one *method* per *test case*, probably within the same test class representing a topic or feature.

So:

@Test
void testLoginAndOut() ...

@Test testLoginAndOpenHelpDeskPage() ..

Use common routines (e.g. void loginAUser(String name) as usual to prevent duplicated code.

Answer (score 0):

You can repeat your tests with different data by passing dynamically in Junit also as TestNg.

Using [Parameterized](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html) class you can achieve that.

See below post for example.

http://isagoksu.com/2009/development/agile-development/test-driven-development/using-junit-parameterized-annotation/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a Parameterized test with JUnit but you need to use **JUnit 4.11** or greater.   You can see [an example that I made here](https://github.com/djangofan/WebDriverTestingTemplate/blob/master/core/google/src/test/java/qa/webdriver/tests/GoogleTest.java).

Using Gradle, your build dependencies would look like this:

```
dependencies {
    // stored at: %HOMEPATH%/.gradle/caches/artifacts-14/filestore
    compile group: 'org.sikuli', name: 'sikuli-api', version: '1.0.+'
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '2.+'
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.+'
    compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
    compile group: 'commons-lang', name: 'commons-lang', version: '2.+'
    compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.+'
}
```